# Python list comprehension returning only last item

Tags: python, image, python-requests, list-comprehension

I am trying to post multiple files using requests post.

The format that is stated [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.4.3/user/advanced/#post-multiple-multipart-encoded-files) is:

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> multiple_files = [('images', ('foo.png', open('foo.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')),
                      ('images', ('bar.png', open('bar.png', 'rb'), 'image/png'))]
>>> r = requests.post(url, files=multiple_files)
>>> r.text
```

So I am trying to do this with a list comprehension. But only the **last** image is uploading. I have a feeling that the comprehension is overriding the images since all images have the same name '**visuals**'. But I required all of them to have the name '**visuals**'.

```
images=[list of image URLS]
files=[('visuals',(str(index)+'.jpg',requests.get(image).content,'image/jpeg')) for index,image in enumerate(images)]
requests.post(script.php,files=files)
```

For example, if there are 20 images, only 20.jpg is sent to my **script.php**.

Response to answer (not working):

```
  images=response.xpath(root+'/photos//url/text()').extract()
  visuals=[(str(index)+'.jpg',requests.get(image).content,'image/jpeg') for index,image in enumerate(images)]
  requests.post(triggers,data={'json':json.dumps(array)},files={'visuals':visuals})
```

Comment: Wait, if you do it like the documentation with `open` not `request.get`, will it work?

Copy this code:
`files=[('visuals',(str(index)+'.jpg',open(image,'rb'),'image/jpeg')) for index,image in enumerate(images)]`

Comment: but they are urls not local files.

Comment: I suspect that for each iteration of the image, the last in the list is being overwritten. I only get the last image due to the same name I suppose?

Comment: Have you tried printing out the result of your list comprehension to make sure it has the values you think it does?

Answer (score 4):

The `files` argument to `requests.post` is supposed to be a `dict`. See the example [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file). Since you pass it with a `list` object, it will be casted internally to a `dict` object. During the type casting, a latter element will overwrite the former element with the same key value! Since all element in has the same key "visuals", only the last one will remain in the final `dict` object.

This question was already answered in requests' issue page [#737](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/737#issuecomment-7235311).

> The list of tuples you provided to data has dict() called on it. Dictionaries (obviously) don't allow duplicate keys, but your list of tuples has duplicate keys, so the last item in the iterable takes the value for that key ... so I'd assume that this is intended behaviour.

Comment: But this only works for one file. I need multiple files with the same name. When I do a dict with the name, I get an error "too many values to unpack" which indicates its wrong. I will add the code for your suggestion above.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#advanced suggests otherwise than your answer. For multiple with same names it uses tuples that have the same names.

Comment: I am afraid it is not possible to put multiple data field with the same name. This belongs to the undefined behavior in [RFC2388](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388). Both `requests` and `urllib3` don't allow this usage.

Comment: I think the doc is not very clear about this. If you trace the source code, `requests` internally calls `urllib3.encode_multipart_formdata` which turn the tuple or list into a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks. I will just have to loop each image and post it separately.